# How to fix update process in Spring Boot (One-to-Many , One-to-One) via Postman?

Tags: spring-boot, postman, crud

I have a problem about updating the movie.

I wrote a function that is named for "update" in MovieService.

Here is that function which is shown below.

```
public void update(Long id,Movie movie) {

        boolean isUpdatingEmployee = (movie.getId() == id);

        if (isUpdatingEmployee) {
            Movie existingMovie = movieRepository.findById(movie.getId()).get();

            existingMovie.setId(id);
            existingMovie.setName(movie.getName());
            existingMovie.setRating(movie.getRating());
            existingMovie.setDirector(movie.getDirector());
            existingMovie.setGenres(movie.getGenres());
            existingMovie.setCreatedAt(movie.getCreatedAt());

            movieRepository.save(existingMovie);
        }

    }
```

When ı try to update a movie after saving it, I got this kind of JSON result and that's why the update process cannot be done.

```
http://localhost:8082/api/v1/movie/update/1
```

Body Request

```
{
    "name": "MovieC",
    "genres": [
        { 
            "name" : "Adventure"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Action"
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2021-04-28",
    "rating" : 9,
    "director" : {
        "name" : "Director 2"
    }     
}
```

The result of JSON after updating the process.

```
{
    "id": null,
    "name": "MovieC",
    "genres": [
        {
            "id": null,
            "name": "Action"
        },
        {
            "id": null,
            "name": "Adventure"
        }
    ],
    "rating": 9.0,
    "createdAt": "2021-04-28",
    "director": {
        "id": null,
        "name": "Director 2"
    }
}
```

Here is my Movie entity which is shown below.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Movie implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="movie",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Genre> genres;

    private Double rating;

    private LocalDate createdAt;


    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn
    private Director director;
}
```

Here is my Director entity which is shown below.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"movies"})
public class Director implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="director",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Movie> movies;
}
```

Here is my Genre entity which is shown below.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"movie"})
public class Genre implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    private String name;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn
    private Movie movie;
}
```

Here is my sample project link : [Project Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/springboothazelcast)

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code, this is your request:

`http://localhost:8082/api/v1/movie/update/1`

```
{
    "name": "MovieC",
    "genres": [
        { 
            "name" : "Adventure"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Action"
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2021-04-28",
    "rating" : 9,
    "director" : {
        "name" : "Director 2"
    }     
}
```

Now consider this snippet from your code:

```
public void update(Long id,Movie movie) {
    boolean isUpdatingEmployee = (movie.getId() == id);
    if (isUpdatingEmployee) {
    ...
```

Your `id` will be `1` as you've set this in your path variable.
However, `movie.getId()` will be null since I don't see it in your `RequestBody`.

And so:

```
isUpdatingEmployee = (movie.getId() == id)` 
isUpdatingEmployee = (    null      ==  1)
isUpdatingEmployee = false
```

this will always give you `false` so I don't think this will enter in your update logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem because you are returning the same object movie you passed in the body of the post method in the controller -    https://github.com/Rapter1990/springboothazelcast/blob/3157f354a628d418cccb99cfdbd188f594c24e9c/src/main/java/com/springboot/hazelcast/controller/MovieController.java#L64

You should rewrite it to something like this:

```java
    @PostMapping("/save")
    public Movie saveMovie(@RequestBody Movie movie) throws ParseException {
        LOG.info("MovieController | Saving Movie.");
        return movieService.save(movie);
    }
```

Here is the link to CRUDRepository javadocs:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-